# Focus on last row and begin edit after itemsource load in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to make excel like datagrid, in which initially DataGrid has 3 empty rows added. On reaching last rows by user, when cell is being edit then more rows added by `AddMoreValues()` method as you can see `BeginningEdit` event. At this code works fine. But now i want to focus on last rows which were last before `AddMoreValues()` event. how to do that?

on Constructor:

```
void AddValues()
        {
            Datagrid.ItemsSource = null;
            List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
            list.Clear();

            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
            {
                string number = i.ToString();
                Item item = new Item()
                {
                    Code = "",
                    Quantity = ""
                };
                list.Add(item);
            }
            Datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
        }
```

When user reached last rows and begin edit then i've added more rows. for more rows i've write `BeginningEdit` event and apply condition that when rows being edit and row index got equal then more rows will be added as you can see `AddMoreValues()` method.

```
private void Datagrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
        {
            header = (string)Datagrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.Header;

            int counts = Datagrid.Items.Count;
            DataGridCellInfo cell = Datagrid.SelectedCells[0];
            var generator = Datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator;
            int columnIndex = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
            int rowIndex = generator.IndexFromContainer(generator.ContainerFromItem(cell.Item)) + 1;

            //MessageBox.Show(rowIndex.ToString());

            //MessageBox.Show(counts + "," + rowIndex);
            if (rowIndex == counts)
            {
                AddMoreValues();

            }
```

AddMoreValues():

```
 void AddMoreValues()
        {

            List<Item> list = null;

            var GridList = (IList<Item>)Datagrid.ItemsSource;
            list = new List<Item>(GridList);

            Datagrid.ItemsSource = null;


            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                string number = i.ToString();
                Item item = new Item()
                {
                    Code = "",
                    Quantity = ""
                };
                list.Add(item);
            }
            Datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
        }
```

Datagrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

for focus i've wrote this code after `AddMoreValues()` method but did not work

```
Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                DataGrid grid = Datagrid;
                DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
                if (rowContainer != null)
                {
                    DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
                    if (presenter != null)
                    {
                        DataGridCell cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as DataGridCell;

                        if (cell != null)
                        {
                            DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
                            if (!grid.SelectedCells.Contains(dataGridCellInfo))
                            {
                                grid.SelectedCells.Add(dataGridCellInfo);
                            }
                            grid.CurrentCell = dataGridCellInfo;
                            grid.BeginEdit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: I don't understand. Which cell do you want to focus when? When is the AddMoreValues() method even called?

Comment: please see this code.... //MessageBox.Show(counts + "," + rowIndex);
            if (rowIndex == counts)
            {
                AddMoreValues();

            }

Comment: if you dont understand just  help to focus any of cell after AddMoreValues(); method

Comment: Do you want to select the cell only?

Comment: select and beginedit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do the following whenever you want to edit a specific cell:

```
Datagrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
    DataGrid grid = Datagrid;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int columnIndex = 0;
    DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        if (presenter != null)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex) as DataGridCell;
            if (cell != null)
            {
                DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
                if (!grid.SelectedCells.Contains(dataGridCellInfo))
                {
                    grid.SelectedCells.Add(dataGridCellInfo);
                }
                grid.CurrentCell = dataGridCellInfo;
                grid.BeginEdit();
            }
        }
    }
}), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```